# How can I align 2 buttons on the middle of the left and right sides of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a frame containing a picture, I would like to add 2 buttons on the left and right side of it so users can click on those to view different pictures. I can handle JavaScript but I can't figure out a way to align these 2 buttons in proper positions. Thank you.

```css
.frame {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.btn {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btnLeft {
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.btnRight {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="btn btnLeft"></div>
<div class="btn btnRight"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track but needed `justify-content: space-between;` not `justify-content: center;` and you needed to put `.btnLeft` and `.btnRight` inside `.frame`.

Here's what different values of `justify-content` do:

[image]

<sub>Image from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)</sub>

```css
.frame {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* not center */
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.btn {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btnLeft{
  background: red;
}

.btnRight {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="btn btnLeft"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="btn btnRight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although the accepted answer works, this should me the accepted answer  IMHO because it follows through on the use of `flexbox` and flexbox properties originally used by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put the buttons inside the frame so you can reference the `left` and `right` positions. Then make those buttons `position:absolute` then set `left` and `right` position for each buttons

Code:

```
.frame {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.btn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
.btnLeft{
  left: 0;
}
.btnRight{
  right: 0;
}
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y0ty7t80/3/

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. The answer will be accepted in 3 minutes.

Comment: @LouisTran, also make sure that `.frame` has `position: relative;` set  as Suthan Bala has done. Otherwise the left and right buttons will align themselves to some other ancestor element. Adding `position: relative;` makes sure they are positioned within `.frame`. That's if you intend not to use flex. Otherwise use Justin Taddei's answer.

Comment: @LouisTran Also, `position: relative;` and `display: flex` together doesn't work right on iOS and my break other parts of your layout later on. You're better off using nothing but `display: flex`, see my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

First you could set the position of the frame to relative so it gets set as a root for following positionings. You could then set the positions of the two buttons both to "absolute" and put them inside of your frame so they get taken out of the text flow. By setting both to a left/right property of 0 and a top property of 50% they get placed exactly in the middle of the frame. Heres an example of what i mean:

```css
.frame {
  position:relative;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.btn {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btnLeft{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  background: red;
}

.btnRight {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
   <div class="btn btnLeft"></div>
   <div class="btn btnRight"></div> 
   <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Im sorry something went bad while pasting it in, i just edited it.